# Can someone explain why this finds the sum of my numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

Im so sorry, I know this is a total noob question but I was running code for my intro class and, through the gracious help of the internet, figured out how to make it work. My only question is *why* does this work? It only looks like it's adding against total and not the other numbers. Thanks for all the help, I know its such a silly question haha.

```
def main():

    #opening the numbers file
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    total = 0
    #making a for loop
    for line in numbers:
        total += int(line)
    print("The sum for all numbers in the numbers.txt file is:", total)

#calling main
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

edit: thank you all so much for the responses(and the new line of code for the sum function! I didn't know that. How cool!). I literally just made an acct so I'm not familiar w/ the website layout at all but I think I've got it down now. Thank you again for explaining it!! :)

Comment: For each line, it gets the number on that line [hence `int`] and then adds that to the total, exactly what sum means. Let me know if you would like me to write this as a formal answer.

Comment: You can use the [edit] link below your post to change it instead of commenting

Comment: It is adding against `total`. Think of it as a container. You keep adding the next number into it... `total` will have the sum of previous numbers when you get to the next number in the loop

Comment: Maybe in-place add (`+=`) is confusing? `total += int(line)` is equivalent to `total = total + int(line)`

Answer (score -1):

`total` is the running sum, so it *is* adding against the other numbers. `+=` is augmented addition: It adds to the existing value of `total`. Its the same as

```
total = total + int(line)
```

That shows how the sum accumulating in the `for` loop. As a side note, there is a function to do sums for you. Normally one would write

```
total = sum(int(line) for line in numbers)
```